# Webservice convert from string to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Tags: c#, string, sqlconnection

I'm trying to get an list of items from some table of SQL Server. I'm doing it with Visual Studio 2010.

That's my code:

```
static string filter = "25";

DataSet Datos = new DataSet();
SqlConnection MyConnection = default(SqlConnection);
SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = default(SqlDataAdapter);
MyConnection = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=false;User ID=SQLUser;Password=SQLPass;");
MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Comment FROM MyTable WHERE [No_] = "+filter+" , MyConnection);
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
MyDataAdapter.Fill(Datos);
MyDataAdapter.Dispose();
MyConnection.Close();
```

I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

On this line:

```
MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Comment FROM MyTable WHERE [No_] = "+filter+" , MyConnection);
```

So, how can I put the string into my `SqlConnection`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you have is correct, there must be something else you're missing.  Have you dug into the stack trace to be sure where the exception is coming from?

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Copied and pasted, and the data adapter line is missing some part of your command string. (I don't think this is your solution, just a copy paste error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
string filter = "10";

DataSet Datos = new DataSet();
string connectionString = "<your connection string here>";
string selectCommand = 
  "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id = " + filter;
using (var MyConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, MyConnection))
{
   MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   MyDataAdapter.Fill(Datos);
}
```

This is basically your code, with the using syntax. Give this a try and post if you still have problems. Good luck!